# Lightweight JMS broker

Tags: java, jms, messaging

I'm looking for a small and yet efficient enough lightweight JMS broker solution with no or minimum of dependencies. My messaging code should be running in the environment with a lot of dependencies I have no control of. Thus it would make ridiculous to deploy say ActiveMQ solution along with my custom bunch of classes.

Comment: So you don't have a say over if your code can depend on activemq classes or not?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently I'm investigating [FFMQ](http://timewalker74.github.io/ffmq/) solution. It's open source (GNU LGPL license), has only 4 dependencies (commons-logging, log4j, jms and jmx),  and it's mature enough to accomplish my goals.

Comment: is there any pointers on how to send and receive messages over a queue created in FFMQ. I googled it but never found one.

Comment: I like small projects :) Has FFMQ common wire protocols, to integrate not only with java?

Answer (score 5):

Especially if you're using spring, don't count activemq out.  You can also run it as an embedded server, and it isn't really all that heavyweight.

Look at:
   http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html

Comment: My code is running in a healthy server environment with the fixed set of dependencies. Usage of Spring container along with ActiveMQ broker would compromise server (dependencies could be overridden, possible class loading issues etc). So I ruled out such heavy solutions in the first place

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use spring in this configuration.  You can start the embedded broker purely from java.  By itself, activemq doesn't have many external dependencies.  That said, I understand what you're saying about trying to keep things as lightweight as possible.

Comment: I tried to deploy ActiveMQ at first, but it has crashed the ecosystem of my server. It proved to have just enough of dependencies to break it))

Comment: That and every solaris server I have tried to get ActiveMQ on it crashes after a few days with no errors being reported.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are looking for lightweight solutions for JMS provider and dont want go with (EMS, Apache etc.) but still need to use JMS.

Have a look at [*Building a Lightweight JMS Provider*](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184405687;jsessionid=JJR0SNWULJUGLQE1GHRSKH4ATMY32JVN) may be this is what you need.

Comment: If someone had 2015 tutorial about lightweight JMS I would be happy

Answer (score 2):

If `JMS` is not a hard requirement, and you are simply looking for a Messaging/Event system, you  should take a look at Java EE 6 Events:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-ee6-events-lightweight

Answer (score 1):

However ActiveMQ distribution is large, it can be shrinked down to a few jar about 3MB all